# How can I change the top bar color python

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

hello how to change the top bar color from windows provided i using wxpython
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQZv5.png)

code

```
window = wx.Frame(None, title = "test con", ) 
window.SetSize(1024,920)
window.SetIcon(wx.Icon("eq.ico"))
window.SetBackgroundColour('#b4e4ed')
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to change the top bar, or formally called the title bar. The best/only way to do this is create your own title bar. [Here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Customized%20frame%20%28Phoenix%29) is more about custom title bar make in wxPython.